# Gallery Next/prev specific to div content

Tags: jquery, gallery, parent-child

I'm a complete noob to JQUERY, learning things slowly. But I have been downloaded an existing [jquery fullscreen gallery](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/05/14/sliding-panel-photo-wall-gallery-with-jquery/), although it works great for a single div , if I wanted to have several divs  with different thumbs, the gallery breaks (next/prev tracks all items in all divs called "content").

Here is the jquery code:

```
// SLIDE PANEL GALLERY

 $(function() {
            /* this is the index of the last clicked picture */
            var current = -1;
            /* number of pictures */
            var totalpictures = $('.content img').size();
            /* speed to animate the panel and the thumbs wrapper */
            var speed   = 500;

            /* show the content */
            $('.content').show();

            /*
            when the user resizes the browser window,
            the size of the picture being viewed is recalculated;
             */
            $(window).bind('resize', function() {
                var $picture = $('#wrapper').find('img');
                resize($picture);
            });

            /*
            when hovering a thumb, animate it's opacity
            for a cool effect;
            when clicking on it, we load the corresponding large image;
            the source of the large image is stored as 
            the "alt" attribute of the thumb image
             */


            $('.content > img').hover(function () {
                var $this   = $(this);
                $this.stop().animate({'opacity':'1.0'},200);
            },function () {
                var $this   = $(this);
                $this.stop().animate({'opacity':'0.4'},200);
            }).bind('click',function(){
                var $this   = $(this);

                /* shows the loading icon */
                $('#loading').show();

                $('<img/>').load(function(){
                    $('#loading').hide();

                    if($('#wrapper').find('img').length) return;
                    current     = $this.index();
                    var $theImage   = $(this);
                    /*
                    After it's loaded we hide the loading icon
                    and resize the image, given the window size;
                    then we append the image to the wrapper
                    */

                    resize($theImage);

                    $('#wrapper').append($theImage);
                    /* make its opacity animate */
                    $theImage.fadeIn(800);

                    /* and finally slide up the panel */
                    $('#panel').animate({'height':'100%'},speed,function(){
                        /*
                        if the picture has a description,
                        it's stored in the title attribute of the thumb;
                        show it if it's not empty
                         */
                        var title = $this.attr('title');

                        if(title != '') 
                            $('#description').html(title).show();
                        else 
                            $('#description').empty().hide();


                        /*
                        if our picture is the first one,
                        don't show the "previous button"
                        for the slideshow navigation;
                        if our picture is the last one,
                        don't show the "next button"
                        for the slideshow navigation
                         */
                        if(current==0)
                            $('#prev').hide();
                        else
                            $('#prev').fadeIn();
                        if(current==parseInt(totalpictures-1))
                            $('#next').hide();
                        else
                            $('#next').fadeIn();
                        /*
                        we set the z-index and height of the thumbs wrapper 
                        to 0, because we want to slide it up afterwards,
                        when the user clicks the large image
                         */
                        $('#thumbsWrapper').css({'z-index':'0','height':'0px'});
                    });
                }).attr('src', $this.attr('alt'));
            });

            /*
            when hovering a large image,
            we want to slide up the thumbs wrapper again,
            and reset the panel (like it was initially);
            this includes removing the large image element
             */
            $('#wrapper > img').live('click',function(){
                $this = $(this);
                $('#description').empty().hide();

                $('#thumbsWrapper').css('z-index','10')
                .stop()
                .animate({'height':'100%'},speed,function(){
                    var $theWrapper = $(this);
                    $('#panel').css('height','0px');
                    $theWrapper.css('z-index','0');
                    /* 
                    remove the large image element
                    and the navigation buttons
                     */
                    $this.remove();
                    $('#prev').hide();
                    $('#next').hide();
                });
            });

            /*
            when we are viewing a large image,
            if we navigate to the right/left we need to know
            which image is the corresponding neighbour.
            we know the index of the current picture (current),
            so we can easily get to the neighbour:
             */
            $('#next').bind('click',function(){
                var $this           = $(this);
                var $nextimage      = $('.content img:nth-child('+parseInt(current+2)+')');
                navigate($nextimage,'right');
            });
            $('#prev').bind('click',function(){
                var $this           = $(this);
                var $previmage      = $('.content img:nth-child('+parseInt(current)+')');
                navigate($previmage,'left');
            });

            /*
            given the next or previous image to show,
            and the direction, it loads a new image in the panel.
             */
            function navigate($nextimage,dir){
                /*
                if we are at the end/beginning
                then there's no next/previous
                 */
                if(dir=='left' && current==0)
                    return;
                if(dir=='right' && current==parseInt(totalpictures-1))
                    return;
                $('#loading').show();
                $('<img/>').load(function(){
                    var $theImage = $(this);
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    $('#description').empty().fadeOut();

                    $('#wrapper img').stop().fadeOut(500,function(){
                        var $this = $(this);

                        $this.remove();
                        resize($theImage);

                        $('#wrapper').append($theImage.show());
                        $theImage.stop().fadeIn(800);

                        var title = $nextimage.attr('title');
                        if(title != ''){
                            $('#description').html(title).show();
                        }
                        else
                            $('#description').empty().hide();

                        if(current==0)
                            $('#prev').hide();
                        else
                            $('#prev').show();
                        if(current==parseInt(totalpictures-1))
                            $('#next').hide();
                        else
                            $('#next').show();
                    });
                    /*
                    increase or decrease the current variable
                     */
                    if(dir=='right')
                        ++current;
                    else if(dir=='left')
                        --current;
                }).attr('src', $nextimage.attr('alt'));
            }

            /*
            resizes an image given the window size,
            considering the margin values
             */
            function resize($image){
                var windowH      = $(window).height()-150;
                var windowW      = $(window).width()-80;
                var theImage     = new Image();
                theImage.src     = $image.attr("src");
                var imgwidth     = theImage.width;
                var imgheight    = theImage.height;

                if((imgwidth > windowW)||(imgheight > windowH)){
                    if(imgwidth > imgheight){
                        var newwidth = windowW;
                        var ratio = imgwidth / windowW;
                        var newheight = imgheight / ratio;
                        theImage.height = newheight;
                        theImage.width= newwidth;
                        if(newheight>windowH){
                            var newnewheight = windowH;
                            var newratio = newheight/windowH;
                            var newnewwidth =newwidth/newratio;
                            theImage.width = newnewwidth;
                            theImage.height= newnewheight;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        var newheight = windowH;
                        var ratio = imgheight / windowH;
                        var newwidth = imgwidth / ratio;
                        theImage.height = newheight;
                        theImage.width= newwidth;
                        if(newwidth>windowW){
                            var newnewwidth = windowW;
                            var newratio = newwidth/windowW;
                            var newnewheight =newheight/newratio;
                            theImage.height = newnewheight;
                            theImage.width= newnewwidth;
                        }
                    }
                }
                $image.css({'width':theImage.width+'px','height':theImage.height+'px'});
            }
        });
```

How do I modify the code to allow me to have multiple content divs and the next/prev only correspond to that content div (parent div?) and not to others on the page?

If anybody could help, it would be greatly appreciated. Happy to provide the css/html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I hope this one works! http://jsbin.com/uwafi6/5

<strike>I've done it for you, here: http://jsbin.com/uwafi6/4</strike>

Change the first line to:

```
jQuery.fn.createGallery = function() {
```

You'll have to change all instances of #next and #prev to classes, .next and .prev

You'll also need to add `var gallery = this;` somewhere near the start so you can use:

`gallery.find('.next')` and `gallery.find('.prev')` wherever there's `$('#next')` or `$('#prev')`

You'll need to change any other id's to classes with the same method.

You can then use `$('#myFirstGallery').createGallery();` to create an instance of the gallery.

You'll find a lot more info here: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Plug_me:_Writing_your_own_plugins

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have tried to implement as you have indicated but I can't seem to quite understand the changes and its not quite working. The HTML is like this: <div id="content"><img></img><img><img></div>

Comment: Hi calum, thanks for going to so much trouble to helping me out here. Unfortunately the gallery still quite doesn't work. For example if I click first image on gallery2 and then go next, it shows the 2nd image from gallery1 (which is the original problem I had). Also when I close the fullscreen view and go back to thumbs, I can't click on other images to look at them anymore. Code has 17 errors, says JSBIN. So sorry for the trouble, thanks for your help so far. Maybe this is too much to ask for.

Comment: Oh that's weird, it was working for me earlier. I must have broken something! Give me a sec.

Comment: Fixed it http://jsbin.com/uwafi6/5 You may need to play with the css but that shouldn't be a huge problem. Hope you get it working :)

Comment: Hi Calum, thank you so much, brilliant piece of re-coding, I think I understand it better too. Have implemented it into my site and hopefully will work out fine.